# Assign class method result to constructor parameter

Tags: javascript, prototype

Need to update constructor value based on the operation made on method `increaseNumber`. This is the original code:

```
function Div() {
    this.numCount = 0;
    this.increaseNumber();
    this.element = document.createElement( 'div' );   
    this.element.innerHTML = "<p class='counter'>" + this.numCount +"</p>";
  }

Div.prototype.increaseNumber = function() {
    this.numCount++;
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.increaseNumber();   
    }.bind(this), 1000);
  }
```

I've tried assigning `this.numCount = this.increaseNumber()`, also tried placing `this.increaseNumber` inside value of innerHTML but nothing works.

Im getting on console the correct values, the number is increasing but I just cannot display inside divs.

Comment: [MDN: Using custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you're changing the value of `numCount` (*model*), you need to update the DOM (*view*) with the new value ("re-render").

Try to extract the part that assigns the value to `this.element.innerHTML` into a different function and call it both in the constructor and upon `increaseNumber()`:

```
function Div() {
    this.numCount = 0;
    this.element = document.createElement( 'div' );
    this.increaseNumber();
    this.renderElement();
}

Div.prototype.renderElement = function renderElement() {
    this.element.innerHTML = "<p class='counter'>" + this.numCount +"</p>";
}

Div.prototype.increaseNumber = function() {
    this.numCount++;
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.increaseNumber();   
      this.renderElement();
    }.bind(this), 1000);
}
```